# How to get specific word in a statement between '(' and the next white-space

Tags: python, regex

So I have a bunch of strings that have this basic setup `TeamName (GMName - Tier)` I'm trying to find a good way to get the GMName from that string.

I tried using this regex: 
`\(\w*\s`
but that gives me `(GMName` which I would then have to parse in some way to get the GMName only. Is there a regex or some Python function that I can use in a single line to get what I want?

Comment: Just use `re.findall(r'\((\w+)\s', s)`, `re.findall` with a pattern containing a single capturing group. No need in lookarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use look arounds if you just want it to check for surrounding strings without them getting captured into the match text. You this regex,

```
(?<=\()\w*\b
```

Here, `(?<=\()` ensures, the word is preceded by literal `(` and `\b` ensures it is a word boundary.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ptdd7r/1)**

Sample python code,

```
import re
s = 'TeamName (GMName - Tier)'
arr = re.findall(r'(?<=\()\w*\b', s)
print(arr)
```

Prints,

```
['GMName']
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a lookbehind for the open paren, or use a capture group.

Lookbehind

```
>>> pat = re.compile(r"""
... (?<=\()       # asserts that a literal ( precedes the following:
... \S+           # one or more non-spaces
... """, re.X)
>>> pat.search("TeamName (GMName - Tier)").group()
"GMName"
```

Capture groups

```
>>> pat = re.compile(r"""
... \(            # a literal (
... (\S+)         # capture one or more non-space characters
... """, re.X)
>>> pat.search("TeamName (GMName - Tier)").group(1)
"GMName"
```